# Sync Assembla SVN and Github Git repos

Tags: svn, git, github

I want to merge the two repository systems: Assembla and Github.

My requirement is: if i do commit the repository in the assembla(**svn**), the repository in the github(**git**) should also be committed automatically and vice versa.

Thanx for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Wy do you want to use both svn and git?  Keeping both in sync if you make changes on both sides is going to be a *giant* nightmare.  If you use svn mainly, setting up a git mirror isn't too hard.  If you use git mainly, you really have no reason to make an svn mirror.

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna take a look at [this crash course](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html) on Git and SVN.

Pushing to a remote gihub repo, it'd be really easy to push to the svn repo too, with a git hook, see [`git help hooks`](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks). Set up a commit hook, to update your SVN repo, on git commit or push, or whenever you like.

I don't know how that's done from the SVN prespective. I do know that Assembla offers git repos too. So it'd be way easier to keep two git repos in sync, than one SVN and one Git.